# Sysinfo behaves differently on RPI4(Raspbian) and CM4(Raspbian)

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, sysinfo

I am using Sysinfo library to calculate ram usage but it gives different results in RPI4 and CM4. It works fine in RPi4 but it returns ridiculous values ​​in CM4. For example,

Sysinfo return totalram  300kB, freeram 308kB, bufferram 9kB.

I looked at the possibility that it might be due to the kernel versions, but there is no difference in the versions.

- CM4(Raspbian) kernel version 5.10.63-v7l+
- RPI4(Raspbian) kernel version 5.10.17-v7l+

Code :

```
        inline static void GetRamCache ()
        {
            char iwbuffer[1024];
            memset(iwbuffer, 0, 1024);
            FILE *iwFile;
            std::string cmd = "cat /proc/meminfo | grep Cached | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1";
            iwFile = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
            fread(iwbuffer, 1, sizeof(iwbuffer) - 1, iwFile);
            fclose(iwFile);

            mCachedRam = std::stoul(std::string(iwbuffer),nullptr,0);
        }

        inline static double GetMemoryUsagePercent (bool ForceGetMemoryCache = true)
        {
            unsigned long mFreeRam = 0;
            unsigned long mBufferRam = 0;
            unsigned long mRamUsed = 0;
            double mPercentageRamUsed = 0;
            struct sysinfo RamInfo;

            if(mCachedRam == 0 || ForceGetMemoryCache)
            {
                GetRamCache();
            }

            try
            {
                if(sysinfo(&RamInfo) != -1)
                {
                    mFreeRam = RamInfo.freeram / 1024; // byte to kB.
                    mBufferRam = RamInfo.bufferram / 1024;

                    if(mTotalRam == 0)
                    {
                        mTotalRam = RamInfo.totalram / 1024;
                    }

                    mRamUsed = (mTotalRam - (mFreeRam + mBufferRam + mCachedRam)) ; //kB
                    mPercentageRamUsed = (((double)mRamUsed / (double)mTotalRam) * 100);
                }
            }
            catch(...)
            {
                std::cout << "GetMemoryUsagePercent EX1" << std::endl;
            }

            return mPercentageRamUsed;
        }
```

Comment: What value is produced in `RamInfo.mem_unit` (memory unit size in bytes)?

Comment: mem_unit returned 0 (RPI4).

In addition,

I tried it on another CM4, it does not work there either. The issue is currently exited from CM4 and RPI4. Because it does not work in other CM4.

Comment: `awk '/^Cached:/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo` avoids unnecessary processes.

Comment: `mem_unit` shouldn't be 0. It's normally 1 but could be 4096.

Comment: @stark Can you write more descriptively?

Comment: @IanAbbott If i call RamInfo.mem_unit above the " if(sysinfo(&RamInfo) != -1) " block, it keeps returning 0. But if i call it inside the if block, it returns 1 or 4096.

In addition, if you dont use " if(sysinfo(&RamInfo) != -1) " all values ​​are returning nonsense.

I guess, if im not wrong " if(sysinfo(&RamInfo) != -1) " returns information on overall system statistics. That is why i think that when i dont use it, it returns nonsense values.

Comment: moreover,  i changed mFreeRam calculation like that : mFreeRam = (RamInfo.freeram * RamInfo.mem_unit) / 1024;

there is no problem at the moment.

Comment: You might need to do `mFreeRam = ((unsigned long long)RamInfo.freeram * RamInfo.mem_unit) / 1024;` (and similarly for `totalram` etc.) to avoid arithmetic overflow on 32-bit systems with at least 4 GiB of RAM.